# Can Common Data Services be used to flow data from other systems than CRM dynamics?

Tags: common-data-service

I am looking into the Common Data Service and Common Data Model from microsoft and found the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-platform/admin/data-integrator

The article lists sources as

- Dynamics 365 for sales
- CDS for Apps
- Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations

I am designing a system that has an legacy ERP system and Dynamics 365 as data sources, that will be using the Common data model with accelerators ontop.

We will have a warehouse (SQL DB maybe) that will hold the common data model and data from the two sources will flow to this warehouse such future solutions can subscribe to data from here.

Can CDS be used as the integration platform/solution to flow/sync data from the source systems to the warehouse, and flow/sync data from the warehouse to source systems ?

or is CDS only for when Dynamics is the warehouse and a connection between the Power Platform and Dynamics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poul,

Currently, the Data Integrator does not have a target connector for a Warehouse product or for SQL DB. CDS without Data Integrator is a valid option, as it has a Web API and many connectors, but one would have to use a tool(Data Factory, Logic Apps, SSIS, etc..) to move the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the data connectors that I can see currently in our tenant.

[image]